# Running Ubuntu on Chromebook 11

Tags: chromebook

Is it possible to install and run Ubuntu on an Acer Chromebook 11 Celeron N3060?

I know of many acer chromebooks that allow Linux, but I am unsure about the 195$ 11 from Acer.

Comment: I'm ready to accept and evaluate comments to the contrary, but it seems to me that this question should remain open because the Acer 11 Chromebook N3060 in the question has an Intel Celeron processor.

Answer (score 1):

There is a program out the called "crouton".
https://lifehacker.com/how-to-install-linux-on-a-chromebook-and-unlock-its-ful-509039343
Here's where I started.

I'm running it on an ARM processor with a few problems I have yet to figure out. I've run both KDE and Gnome. Works but is a bit rough.